# Django: self referential foreign key with choice list

Tags: python, django, class, django-models

My model defines an employee, which has a name, ID, job, and manager. I'd like to be able to specify a list of choices of Employees that could be listed as another employees manager (similar to the jobs field). To do so I have included

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    EXECUTIVE = 'EXC'
    SALESMAN = 'SAL'
    ENGINEER = 'ENG'
    CLERK = 'CLK'
    JOBS = (
        (EXECUTIVE, 'Executive'),
        (SALESMAN, 'Salesman'),
        (ENGINEER 'Engineer'),
        (CLERK, 'Clerk'),
    )
    employee_id = models.CharField(max_length = 5, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    job = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=JOBS) 
    is_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    manager = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, choices=get_managers()) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Also in my models.py I have defined the following function:

```
def get_managers():
    managers = []
    for manager in Employee.objects.filter(is_manager=True):
        managers.append((manager.employee_id, manager.name))
    return managers
```

My problem is that when the function is placed before the Employee class definition I get `NameError: name 'Employees' is not defined`  and when placed after the Employee class definition the error `NameError: name 'get_managers()' is not defined`. I have tried placing the `get_managers()` within the class and get `NameError: name 'get_managers()' is not defined

If there are better ways of accomplishing the same thing I would be open to suggestions.

Comment: Are you using any forms? or Is this in django admin?

Comment: As Andrey has suggested in his answer, this shouldn't really be a `choice` field, since data dependent. You should keep the logic separate from the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Django docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices

> Finally, note that choices can be any iterable object — not
>   necessarily a list or tuple. This lets you construct choices
>   dynamically. But if you find yourself hacking choices to be dynamic,
>   you're probably better off using a proper database table with a
>   ForeignKey. choices is meant for static data that doesn't change much,
>   if ever.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django admin, You can do it.

```
class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(EmployeeAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['manager'].queryset = Employee.objects.filter(is_manager=True)
        return form
```

Then in models

```
manager = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
```

In `admin.py`

```
admin.site.register(Employee, EmployeeAdmin)
```